# How to get the animated view

Tags: android, animation, view

here is xml file：

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
   android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

here is java code

```
private Button text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (Button)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text.startAnimation(getScaleAnimation());

        }
    });
}

    private ScaleAnimation getScaleAnimation(){
    ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(1f,1.2f,1f,1.2f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    return animation;
}
```

I am performing a simple ScaleAnimation on a Button.Is there any way I can get the animated view?

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/apply-animation-on-button.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I very sorry about my english that misunderstood what I said.I know how to use animation that apply on view so that the view can being animated whatever you want.But I want to get the animated view which you apply animation before.Sorry about my english!

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you should support some detailed information about what you are trying to ask to make it clear. Maybe including an image would be a good idea or just example cenario...

Comment: Thank you!I think I should to learn english first. - -!

Answer (score 3):

Just open `anim` folder inside `res` folder. Create an `xml` file. Then you need to create `set` tag. Inside of it, you can create `scale` tag.

Here is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">

<scale  
    android:fromXScale="0.5"
    android:toXScale="2"
    android:fromYScale="0.5"
    android:toYScale="2"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="5000"

    />

</set>
```

Note: do not forget to include `xmlns:android` declaration.

Now, inside of `onCreate` method or wherever you want, just put following. I am animating(scaling) a button itself when it is clicked:

```
    Button but = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationActivity.this, R.anim.animation);
            but.startAnimation(anim);
    }
});
```

**EDIT:**
in case you want to rotate it while scaling, you can put following inside of the `xml` file:

```
<rotate 
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="5000"
    />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I very sorry about my english that misunderstood what I said.I know how to use animation that apply on view so that the view can being animated whatever you want.But I want to get the animated view which you apply animation before.Sorry about my english!

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

Create an xml inside `/res/anim` folder and put the below code into it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<set xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

       <scale android:fromXScale="0.0" android:fromYScale="0.0"
              android:toXScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0" 
              android:duration="700" android:fillBefore="false" />

</set>
```

Place the below code inside the java file:

```
Animation scaleAnimation 
           = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.logoanimation); 
Btn.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

`logoanimation` is the name of my animation xml file.

for more refer this [tutorial](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2008/04/animated-views.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!I very sorry about my english that misunderstood what I said.I know how to use animation that apply on view so that the view can being animated whatever you want.But I want to get the animated view which you apply animation before.Sorry about my english!